# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'property'

Tags: java, xml, spring

sorry if this question has been already answered - I have found several answers for usual source of this problem such as using  and having no xmlns:beans declaration but what I get seems different... So here's my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" />

<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

<beans:bean id="authMessageHandler" class="xxx.AuthenticationMessageHandler" />

<!-- **************************** -->
<!-- Security configuration for REST services. -->
<http pattern="/consultants/**" 
    authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" entry-point-ref="restServicesEntryPoint"
    create-session="stateless">
    <custom-filter ref="restServicesFilter"
        before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
</http>

<!-- Entry point for REST service. -->
<beans:bean id="restServicesEntryPoint" class="xxx.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint" />

<!-- Filter for REST services. -->
<beans:bean id="restServicesFilter" class="xxx.RestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="postOnly" value="false" />
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="restServicesSuccessHandler" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- A handler for successful REST service authentication. -->
<beans:bean id="restServicesSuccessHandler" class="xxx.RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
<!-- **************************** -->

<http access-denied-page="/public/auth/denied.html" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false">
    <!--Define our custom login page-->
    <form-login login-page="/auth/login"
        default-target-url="/main"
        always-use-default-target="true"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="authMessageHandler" />

    <session-management invalid-session-url="/auth/invalid-session"></session-management>

    <!-- Not logged in only have access to the login pages. -->
    <intercept-url pattern= 
        <!-- stuff -->
    />

    <logout logout-success-url="/auth/login" invalidate-session="false" />
</http>
```

Stuff between asterisks is what I added to already working xml and I get 3 error mentioned in the question's title on lines:

```
<property name="postOnly" value="false" />
<property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
<property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="restServicesSuccessHandler" />
```

I don't understand why. Can I get any advice on what's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root element has

```
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
```

therefore these elements:

```
<property name="postOnly" value="false" />
<property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
<property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="restServicesSuccessHandler" />
```

are in the `http://www.springframework.org/schema/security` namespace when they should be in the `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans` one.  You need to use

```
<beans:property name="postOnly" value="false" />
<beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
<beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="restServicesSuccessHandler" />
```

instead.

Comment: I am sure I have tried that before but tried it now again and works. Probably last time I had other issues... Thanks!